Fixed points of an idempotent map is a retract
Let $e\circ e = e : X \rightarrow X$. We want to show that the space of fixed points of $e$ is a retract of $X$. Call such a space $F$.
For that notice that such space of fixed points is the equalizer of $e$ and the identity. The map of the equalizer $F \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion map, and we will call it $\iota$.
Then since $e\circ e = e$ we have that there's a unique $r : X \rightarrow F$ such that $\iota\circ r = e$.
This is almost a retract but not quite. What am I missing?

For a retract, you need to show that the composition $$F\xrightarrow{\iota}X\xrightarrow{r} F$$ is the identity. Your choice of $r = e\equiv e\circ e$ is a great choice! This is because it is a map to $F$, namely $e(e(x)) = e(x)$, so for every $x$, $e(x)\in F$, since the definition of $F$ is $$F:=\bigg\{y\mid e(y) = y\bigg\}.$$ Now, we need to check that for $f\in F$, we get the identity after we compose $r\circ \iota = e \circ \iota$. We get $$ e(f) = f$$ which is the identity! We're done!

This is a bit obfuscated. $e\circ e$ works but so does $r=e$

Fair, I edited it to be just $e$ in most cases.

Hi. Thanks for the answer. I'm gonna leave here a comment with the proof with the inclusion explicit. The idea was simply to consider: $\iota\circ r\circ\iota = e\circ\iota = \iota = \iota\circ id$; where the first equality is by the definition of $r$ and the second one by the definition of $\iota$ (as an equalizer). Then since $\iota$ is monic we have $\iota\circ r = id$, which is what we wanted.
